# Multisites can't load .php files

Tags: multisite

I'm trying to setup a multisite environment with subdirectories and somehow I'm getting a **"File not found."** error every time I'm trying to access a .php file. It seems to work fine with all other file types and I tried to manually access files of different types in the same folder, so it seems to be something about that .php ending, that causes the problem. 
I had the same problem before with css files, which was fixed by adding `define('CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS', false);` to **wp-config.php**, but that didn't fix the problems for **php** files.

It works fine for the main site, but all the subsites have the issue. The url pattern I'm using to access the files is [website_name]/test/wp-content/index.php.

This is my htaccess file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

And this is my multisite section in wp-config.php:

```
define('WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true);
define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false);
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'fresenia.man.poznan.pl');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
```

Comment: I had the axact same problem.

My solution: edited/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf. It needs to look like:

Comment: <VirtualHost *:80>

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride all
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/>
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride all
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>